# Change the default background color of kendo dropdownlist angular 6

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I would like to change the default color(grey) in the Kendo dropdown list, could anyone help me how to do that?

**app.html**

```
<kendo-dropdownlist
    #list
    [data]="data"
    [filterable]="true"
    textField="text"
    valueField="value"
    (filterChange)="handleFilter($event)" 
    (selectionChange)="Change($event)"
    [valuePrimitive]="true"
    formControlName = selectSize
>
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
@ViewChild("list") list;

public source: Array<{ text: string, value: number }> = [
    { text: "Small", value: 1 },
    { text: "Medium", value: 2 },
    { text: "Large", value: 3 }
];
```

[image: Trying to change the grey color of dropdown list[1]]

Comment: you need to override the kendo dropdownlist style using their classes like below answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change the color of dropdownlist you need to override kendo dropdownlist classes like below

**style.css**

```
.k-dropdown-wrap>.k-input, .k-dropdown .k-dropdown-wrap .k-select, .k-list, .k-reset {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

**[Here is solution on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kendo-ddl-2issues-xjnqxg?file=styles.css)**

Comment: and how can do that dynamically with [ngClass] or [ngStyle] for example?

Answer (score 0):

```
.k-picker-solid {
 background-color: white;
 background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**